# passing arguments as array of integers

Tags: c++

```
struct G{

    G&operator()(const int**a)
    {
       v<<a;
       std::copy(v.begin(),v.end(),std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
       return *this;
    }
    friend std::vector<int>&operator<<(std::vector<int>&v,const int** n);
    std::vector<int>v;
};

std::vector<int>&operator<<(std::vector<int>&v,const int** n)
{
    v.insert(v.begin(),*n,*n+sizeof(*n)/sizeof(*n[0]));
    return v;
}

/// use it
G g; 
int v[8]={1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4};
g(&v);
```

I have two questions,
1. The above code returns with error `cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int (*)[8]' to 'const int **'`
2. I would like to pass in g as g({1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4}) instead of g(&v). But I don't know how to do that and always wonder if g will accept it.
Thank you.

Comment: Try using something along the lines: `template<size_t N> myFunction( int& myArray[N] )`that way you can prevent it decaying to pointer to int in the function call. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `&v` is giving you the address of the array, when you want the address of a pointer.  Try doing `const int* x = v` then `g(&x)`.
2. In C++0x, you can do this:

   ```
   G& operator()(std::initializer_list<const int>);
   g({1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4});
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you know you will always use a constant array of size 8,

```
struct G{

    G&operator()(int a[8])
    {
       v.reserve(8);
       v.insert(v.begin(), a, a + 8);
       std::copy(v.begin(),v.end(),std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
       return *this;
    }

    std::vector<int>v;
};

/// use it
G g; 
int v[8]={1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4};
g(v);
```

If not, you'll need to pass the size of the array along with the array:

```
struct G{

    G&operator()(int* a, int len)
    {
       v.reserve(len);
       v.insert(v.begin(), a, a + len);
       std::copy(v.begin(),v.end(),std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
       return *this;
    }

    std::vector<int>v;
};

/// use it
G g; 
int v[8]={1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4};
g(v, sizeof(v) / sizeof(int));
```

Or if you're always going to use compile time arrays (from the scope in which they were declared) rather than dynamic arrays,

```
struct G{

    template<unsigned int Len>
    G& operator()(int (&a)[Len])
    {
       v.reserve(Len);
       v.insert(v.begin(), a, a + Len);
       std::copy(v.begin(),v.end(),std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
       return *this;
    }

    std::vector<int>v;
};

/// use it
G g; 
int v[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4};
g(v);
```

But note that the last version will generate a different version of `operator()` for every different size of array you pass it.

Comment: If the code duplication with the template version becomes a problem, you can partially alleviate it by having it forward the array and it's size to the dynamic version, where the actual work will be done.